# ASP.NET Core MVC - Convert HTML table to json and send to controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to send the html table data to controller but its seems like there's something wrong that I did.

Please see my TABLE

```
<table id="List" class="table table-borderless">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Leave ID
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Leave Type
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Date
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Reason
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Action
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and this is how I add data to a table using a modal

```
function AddToList() {
            var LeaveApplicationID = 1;
            var LeaveTypeID = $('#LeaveTypeID').val();
            var LeaveType = $('#LeaveTypeID').find(':selected').text();
            var Date = $('#LeaveDate').val();
            var Reason = $('#Reason').val();

            var html = '';

            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td>" + LeaveApplicationID + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + LeaveTypeID +"</td>";
            html += "<td>" + LeaveType + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + Date + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + Reason + "</td>";
            html += "<td>";
            html += "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'>";
            html += "<span class='fa fa-pencil'></span>";
            html += "</button>";
            html += "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></button></td > ";
            html += "<tr>";

            $('#List').append(html);
        }
```

When clicking the button the function SaveDetails() will be called

```
function SaveDetails() {

            var LeaveList = [];
            LeaveList.length = 0;

            $.each($("#List tbody tr"), function () {
                LeaveList.push({
                    LeaveApplicationID : $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                    LeaveTypeID : $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                    Date : $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html(),
                    Reason : $(this).find('td:eq(4)').html()
                });
            });

            var data = JSON.stringify({
                leaveApplicationDetails: LeaveList
            });

            console.log(data);

             $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveLeaveApplicationDetails")",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

[this is the output of the json string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGHdX.png)

and according to the output i think im getting the right result

however when im tring to send to controller im getting a null.

this is my controller.

controller

```
public IActionResult SaveLeaveApplicationDetails(List<LeaveApplicationDetails> leaveApplicationDetails)
        {
            
            return Json(leaveApplicationDetails);
        }
```

where do you think am I wrong? thank you...

Edited:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmLw9.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeUFc.png)

```
namespace HRMS.Models
{
    public class LeaveApplicationHeader
    {
        [Key]
        public int LeaveApplicationID { get; set; }
        public string LeaveApplicationCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateFiled { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public Employee EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public Department DepartmentCode { get; set; }
        public int WithPay { get; set; }
        public int WithoutPay { get; set; }
        public int SLBalance { get; set; }
        public int VLBalance { get; set; }
        public int SLBalanceCertification { get; set; }
        public int VLBalanceCertification { get; set; }
        public int LeaveStatusID { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeaveApplicationDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int LeaveApplicationID { get; set; }
        public int LeaveTypeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeaveApplication
    {
        public LeaveApplicationHeader LeaveApplicationHeader { get; set; }

        public LeaveApplicationDetails LeaveApplicationDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Another Edited:
not working:

```
$.each($("#List tbody tr"), function () {
            LeaveList.push({
                LeaveApplicationID: 1,
                LeaveTypeID: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                Date: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                Reason: $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text()
            });
        });

        Worked:
    

LeaveList.push({
            LeaveApplicationID: 1,
            LeaveTypeID: 1,
            Date: "2020-07-05",
            Reason: "test1"
        });
        LeaveList.push({
            LeaveApplicationID: 2,
            LeaveTypeID: 2,
            Date: "2020-07-05",
            Reason: "test2"
        });
```

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEstrera,any update?

Comment: hello i tried your suggestion but im still getting a null.

Comment: Can you provide the new output of the json string?

Comment: Please see the edited on my postt.that's what written on the console

Comment: `var data = JSON.stringify(LeaveList);  console.log(data);`See the log.

Comment: You can see my simple demo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSGOK.gif).

Comment: please see my output image on my  edited post

Comment: I see in your Json string, there is an empty {} after each object, I think that is the problem

Comment: i think my real problem is on my output after data , theres "{}"

Comment: yeah precisely, how am I going to fix that?

Comment: After my test, even if {} exists, it can be successfully bound. Have you added [FromBody]?

Comment: I already fix the empty object. Im still getting a null, i even have a [FromBody] on controller,. I tried to insert using Newton.json on my controller. But im still getting the same result. I already seen your gif.

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: Please see my model on edited

Comment: It work well for me ......[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhr0k.png).

Comment: You can see my edit answer and do a simple demo.

Comment: By the way,I think the problem may in your `SaveDetails` function.I guess that your table is in a form,you may not disable the form submission feature.Of course this is just a guess, you can first submit it as a button like in my answer below.

Comment: Now I know where's really my problem on my code sir. I tried to replace my $.each on my SaveDetails  .. Like on your edited comment and it worked.

Comment: please see my another edited comment.

Comment: Change `.text` to `.html`

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: not yet sir, im still researching and looking for an answer sorry T_T

Comment: Can you share the whole View and javascripts?

Comment: I see that,usually when I change to `.html`,it work well for me...It's strange..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code to

```
  var data = JSON.stringify(LeaveList);
```

Then add `[FromBody]` in your controller:

```
public IActionResult SaveLeaveApplicationDetails([FromBody]List<LeaveApplicationDetails> leaveApplicationDetails)
    {
        
        return Json(leaveApplicationDetails);
    }
```

**Edit**

You can try to do a simple demo like me.

View:

```
<button id="click">
click
</button>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>        
        $("#click").click(function() {
            var LeaveList = [];
            LeaveList.length = 0;
            LeaveList.push({
                  LeaveApplicationID: 1,
                  LeaveTypeID: 1,
                  Date: "2020-07-05",
                  Reason: "test1"
                 });
            LeaveList.push({
                LeaveApplicationID: 2,
                LeaveTypeID: 2,
                Date: "2020-07-05",
                Reason: "test2"
            });
            var data = JSON.stringify(LeaveList);
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("SaveLeaveApplicationDetails")",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveLeaveApplicationDetails([FromBody]List<LeaveApplicationDetails> leaveApplicationDetails)
    {
        return Json(leaveApplicationDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```js
var leaveApplicationDetails = JSON.stringify(LeaveList);

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("SaveLeaveApplicationDetails")",
    data: {leaveApplicationDetails: leaveApplicationDetails},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: bruh im still getting a null T_T huhuhu so sad, I spent 3 days trying to solve this problem T_T

Comment: Can you give it a try without `JSON.stringify` (just `var leaveApplicationDetails = LeaveList`)?

Comment: Also check you sample json, it's all wrong. ID can not all be 1, because your first field is [Key] and your date format is wrong (check year)